# wxpython app on ubuntu can not raise after the window clicked

Tags: ubuntu, wxpython

The window of my app is expected to raise to the front if ctrl-shift pressed.

It works fine even if you clicked the minimize button.

But after the window clicked, it can not raise.

part of my code:

```
    if sys.platform == 'darwin':
        self.mac_raise(subproc=True)
    elif sys.platform == 'linux2':
        print self.IsIconized()  # always False
        if self.IsIconized():
            self.Iconize(False)
        self.Show(True)
        self.Raise()
    else:
        if self.IsIconized():
            self.Iconize(False)
        self.Raise()
```

full code: https://github.com/thinker3/youdao my_youdao.py

On Windows7, it works all as expected. On Mac, I copied an osascript to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

a workaround

```
    command = 'wmctrl -a "%s"' % title  # or xdotool
    os.system(command)
```

waiting for a better answer